# How to install Vala on elementary OS

Tags: release-freya, software-installation, programming, vala, ide

I am learning vala. I need to setup vala environment on my elementary OS. How to install Vala on elementary OS?

Comment: https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the elementary [Development Guide](https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started). In the section "[Developer SDK](https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started#developer-sdk)" we cover grabbing essential development libraries, including the Vala compiler.

For development tasks, you're going to be spending a lot of time in Terminal. The command we recommend for grabbing these development essentials is:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep granite-demo
```

The `build-dep` part here is short for "build dependencies". This command tells `apt` to install everything that would be required to build the package `granite-demo`. That not only includes the Vala compiler, but Gtk+ development libraries and other things that you'll want to have if your goal is to develop apps for elementary OS.

If you only want to get the vala compiler and no other development libraries, you can use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install valac
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the vala compiler `valac` :

- from **software center** or
- with terminal command: `sudo apt-get install valac`

---

**IDE Support**:

There are various projects in various states of stability in order to provide IDE support for Vala:

- [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) is an integrated development environment with support for vala syntax and code completion.

  Install from software center or with terminal command: `sudo apt-get install geany`
- [Netbeans](https://github.com/carbonfx/netbeans-valaproject#readme) - Plugin for the Netbeans IDE for Vala
- [Valencia](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Valencia) - Vala plugin for gedit
- [Valama](https://github.com/Valama/valama) - An IDE with glade editor & symbols navigator

Reference : [Vala Tools](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tools)

Useful resources:

[Vala - Documentation](http://valadoc.org/)

[Vala - Compiler for the GObject type system](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala)

[Vala Programming](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Vala_Programming)

[Vala Tutorial](https://live.gnome.org/Vala/Tutorial)

[elementary docs](http://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started#developer-sdk)

Comment: I believe part of this answer is bad advice. Please don't force the installation of a different version as intended by the distribution (and enforced by apt pinning).

Comment: "believe"?? I can only say _silly_  https://askubuntu.com/questions/135339/assign-highest-priority-to-my-local-repository

Comment: @embik IMHO its _better_ if you explain, why? instead of using _believe_.(No one care about someone's belief, but cares facts)

Comment: Embik is right. Pinning wouldn't be done without a reason. In this case, after 0.28 the way concurrent versions are handled has changed and if you're unable to compile an app with 0.30 (because of dependency conflicts), it's not as simple to compile with an earlier version.